# Oracle EBS 12.1.1 for Windows: Where the log file goed for any event occurs on Oracle EBS

Tags: oracle-enterprise-linux

I am looking for the location where all the log file generate when any event like user creation, deletion, Responsibility creation deletion happen. Need to view it for an event when we open an responsibility it throws error saying contact your administrator. Please resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Log files are located under $LOG_HOME top...

User related information and other system related information will be stored in port_number.system.log(i.e:10230.system.log)

Inventory related transactions are located under port_number.INV.log (i.e:10230.INV.log)..

Please elaborate your question in details so  that i can help you more...